# bitset equivalent for unsigned int

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

Writing a program to convert ANSI encoded string to binary. And my ANSI value is È.

Here is how I'm doing this:

```
 int ascii; //used to store ASCII number of a character

int length = strlen(input);
char letter = NULL;
for(int x=0;x<length;x++) //repeat until the input is read
{
    ascii = input[x];
    bitset<8> binary(ascii);
}
```

However, as `ascii` is int type so I'm getting the value as -56 and when finding its binary using `bitset` I'm getting 00110011(which is wrong binary value for character È). Instead I should get the value as 11001000 (correct binary for È).I understand that if the `ascii` type would be `unsigned int`, then I'll get correct binary output. However, `bitset` is not accepting `unsigned int` type; hence, is there any equivalent of `bitset` which would accept `unsighed int`? OR are there any other way to do this binary conversion?

Comment: You have an issue with mixing up signed `int` values and unsigned values.  That should have been obvious, but I guess not.

Comment: What is the type for input? and how do you fill it? I think it is important here.

Comment: What character set are you using, ASCII or ANSI?  The ASCII character set does not contain È.

Answer (score 0):

You have an X-Y problem.

You should be using *wide* or *unicode* variable types.

The `std::bitset` that you are looking for is:
`std::bitset<sizeof(unsigned int) * CHAR_BIT>`.

The `sizeof(unsigned int)` is the number of bytes in an `unsigned int`.
The `CHAR_BIT` is the number of bits in a byte.

Comment: Should I write like this: unsigned int ascii; bitset<sizeof(unsigned int)*CHAR_BIT> binary(ascii); Could you please tell me exactly how should i write?

Comment: ASCII is 7-bit, so you can have `char ascii;`.  ANSI and Unicode need more bits so you will need to have `wchar_t ANSI;` or `unsigned int unicode;`  You question was about `std::bitset`, so I gave you an example.